# DotNetZip: Convert ZipFile to byte[] array

Tags: c#, byte, dotnetzip

I'm using DotNetZip to add a file to a zip archive, which I've read from the file system. I'd like to convert the resulting ZipFile to byte[] array. Any assistance will be highly appreciated. My code is shown below.

```
public byte[] AddPrjFile(FileStream shapeFileZip, Uri prjLocation)
{
    string prjFileAbsPath = prjLocation.AbsolutePath;
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(shapFileZip))
    {
        ZipEntry e = zip.AddFile(prjFileAbsPath);
        e.FileName = zipFile.Name + ".prj";
    }

    return byte_array;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could simply use the [`File.ReadAllBytes` static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes) like:

```
return File.ReadAllBytes( shapeFileZip.Name );
```

To read from your file.

Comment: The question was actually how to convert an instance of ZipFile to byte array, not a FileStream