# Trying to convert a ZipArchiveEntry into a byte[]

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am trying to take a list of `ZipArchiveEntry`s and convert them into byte arrays, but I am logistically running into a wall.

So far I am trying to convert it into a `MemoryStream` to convert it into the byte[] like this:

```
public static void ScanUpload(List<ZipArchiveEntry> scan)
{
    foreach (var s in scan)
    {                           
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

But I have no idea what comes next. or even if this is the right way to go about this. Would someone be able to help?

Comment: Have a look at this thread. It is really simple , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119705/dotnetzip-convert-zipfile-to-byte-array

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be able to read from the stream that `ZipArchiveEntry.Open()` returns:

```
foreach (var s in scan)
{            
    var stream = s.Open();
    byte[] bytes;
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
         stream.CopyTo(ms);
         bytes = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```